# Append an extra member to an object - type intersection vs iteration approach

Tags: typescript

Here is the question: [AppendToObject](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00527-medium-append-to-object/README.md). My first intuition to the question was to use type intersection, e.g,

```
type AppendToObject<T, U extends PropertyKey, V> = T & {[P in U]: V}
```

However, that solution doesn't pass the testcases.

```
type test1 = {
  key: 'cat'
  value: 'green'
}

type testExpect1 = {
  key: 'cat'
  value: 'green'
  home: boolean
}

type test2 = {
  key: 'dog' | undefined
  value: 'white'
  sun: true
}

type testExpect2 = {
  key: 'dog' | undefined
  value: 'white'
  sun: true
  home: 1
}

type test3 = {
  key: 'cow'
  value: 'yellow'
  sun: false
}

type testExpect3 = {
  key: 'cow'
  value: 'yellow'
  sun: false
  moon: false | undefined
}

// reference from 
// https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/utils/index.d.ts
type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false
type Expect<T extends true> = T

type cases = [
  Expect<Equal<AppendToObject<test1, 'home', boolean>, testExpect1>>,
  Expect<Equal<AppendToObject<test2, 'home', 1>, testExpect2>>,
  Expect<Equal<AppendToObject<test3, 'moon', false | undefined>, testExpect3>>,
]
```

So I changed to the iteraction approach and it passes all the testcases.

```
type AppendToObject<T, U extends PropertyKey, V> = {[P in U | keyof T ]: P extends keyof T ? T[P] : V}
```

I'm not seeing anything wrong with the intersection approach, as if I type an object with it, it's also compulsory to specify the extra argument. Does the solution fail the tests just because of how `Equal` is implemented? Or, is there any other nuances between these two approaches that I'm not aware?

Comment: can you include your variables `testX` `testExpectX`

Comment: types look correct with the intersection. maybe the problem is in `Equal`. Can you try [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr3lam)?

Comment: @wonderflame It works! How does `Prettify` make a difference? Could you please post it in the answer thanks!

Comment: sure, will do soon

Comment: Please include the definitions of `Expect` and `Equal` in the question so that it's self-contained.  A link to an external site doesn't suffice, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result types for the `AppendToObject` looks correct. So I suspect the issue is with how the `Equal` compares the types. Example:

```
type test1 = {
  key: 'cat';
  value: 'green';
};
type testExpect1 = {
  key: 'cat';
  value: 'green';
  home: boolean;
};

// type Result = test1 & {
//     home: boolean;
// }
type Result = AppendToObject<test1, 'home', boolean>
```

So the `testExpect1` has no intersection, but the property is directly in one object.

This can be fixed by using the [Prettify](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/prettify.d.ts?plain=1#L15) utility type from the [type-samurai](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai) package. Simplified version:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
      [K in keyof R]: R[K];
    }
  : never;
```

`Prettify` remaps the type which causes to remove the intersection and make the more readable.

Testing:

```
type AppendToObject<T, U extends PropertyKey, V> = Prettify<
  T & { [P in U]: V }
>;

// type Result = {
//   key: 'cat';
//   value: 'green';
//   home: boolean;
// }
type Result = AppendToObject<test1, 'home', boolean>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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)

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense. Just one question on `Prettify` - do you know why do we need `T extends infer R ` because by `[K in keyof T]: T[K]` only seems to do the job as well

Comment: @JaniceZhong It happened to me from time to time when it didn't work directly. Can't recall those cases now